# Elegantly dealing with non numerical elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am trying to run scipys hstack method on a dataframe and a list. To do this effectively I must deal with the non-numerical elements in my list. I want to do this on the fly (i.e I do not wish to edit the csv I am reading from), as elegantly as possible.

The code I am running is as follows :

```
  X = list(np.array(p.read_csv('CSVFile.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])
  OtherColumn = p.read_csv('CSVFile.csv', delimiter=";")[["OtherCol"]]

  X =  sp.sparse.hstack((X, OtherColumn.values))
```

Error :

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('O')
```

This is because my `OtherColumn` column contains a "?" character where there is bad data. The logic I need is kinda as follows, but how can I accomplish this in Python? Apologies, I am a beginner and have struggled with this for a little bit!

```
for(i = 0; i< OtherColumn.size; i++)){
    try:
        X[i] =  sp.sparse.hstack((X[i], OtherColumn.values[i]))
    except Error:
        X[i] =  sp.sparse.hstack((X[i], OtherColumn.avg()))
    }
```

In English, run the normal hstack unless there is a '?' char, then use the average of all OtherColumn values.

Comment: Do  you think you could you do something like:  
`X =  sp.sparse.hstack((X, [value for value in OtherColumn.values if value != "?"]))`

Comment: or `if type(value) != str`, something like this

Comment: you can pass `na_values=['?']` as an argument to `read_csv`.

Comment: @behzad.nouri Can you please link me an example of how this would help me? Is it possible to set na_values to the maximum or average value of the entire `DataFrame` in this way?

Comment: @SimonKiely if a column only has numeric values and missing values, pandas will automatically get the type correctly; with `'?'` mixing in, the column will be parsed as an object, so you need to specify `na_values=['?']` so that `'?'` are parsed as missing values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way to solve this is to specify the "?" as a missing data marker in `read_csv`:

```
df = p.read_csv('CSVFile.csv', delimiter=";", na_values=['?'])[["OtherCol"]]
```

Also, I don't see why you need all the converting to arrays and stacking.  Why not just read the file into a dataframe and then do the manipulation you need in place? It looks like you just want to do

```
df['NewColumn'] = df.OtherColumn.fillna(df.OtherColumn.mean())
```

Comment: No problem, just note that in general you don't actually have to do this. For most calculations Pandas will do The Right Thing with missing values, and keeping them in there makes it easier to do things like count the valid datapoints in each column and calculate correct distributions.

Comment: @chtonicdaemon That's brilliant. Thank you. Am I right in saying it should be `df.fillna(df.OtherColumn.mean())` instead of `df.OtherColumn.fillna(df.OtherColumn.mean())` also? Just a quick observation from when I tried to run it; it seems to run this way for me! :) Thanks :)

Comment: df.fillna will do this for all the columns, while df.OtherColumn.fillna will do it for just that one column. If you want to fill each column with the respective average, use df.fillna(df.mean()).

Comment: If you find this answer to solve your problem, consider marking it as the answer.